# BTYD addecuation in R (List/Vector type matching)

Tags: r, optimization, churn

I am working in a predictive model for churning. Thus, we decided to start to work with NBD/Pareto (BTYD Package, in R).

I think the error ocurrs due to the data compatibility or, maybe, for other reasons that I cannot understand yet.

First, I ran and saw the repository from https://gist.github.com/mattbaggott/5113177
Here they work with the model and get really interesting ggplots and then they make model using their data.

In the instruction that they use *EstimateParameters* function they get the result correctly, with stuff to work with according to the model.

[After pnbd.EstimatesModel function is run in the example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Da2Gl.png)

Thus, I addecuated my data so that we could use that package. I make mi own CBS matrix by hand makin my transformations first and then execute the instruction.
However, I am getting the same error, that tells , literally that

*"Error in optim(logparams, pnbd.eLL, cal.cbs = cal.cbs, max.param.value = max.param.value,  : 
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
In addition: Warning message:
In log(1 - ((maxab + t.x)/(maxab + T.cal))^(r + s + x)) : NaNs produced"*

[Error thrown in my adaptation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Lsgx.png)

I must tell you that I have been trying to solve it a week along and seen same errors produced in other questions but I wasn't able to solve it. 
I look for NAs & infinites, tried to change type of data... but nothing.

Can someone tell me ideas from what ' s happening?